# Two legged oauth2 using Doorkeeper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, oauth, doorkeeper

Could I customize OAuth2 + Doorkeeper + Devise as two legged? Because I guess doorkeeper is three legged if I'm right. It is can customize, how could I do it?

Comment: Two/three legged meaning: http://cakebaker.42dh.com/2011/01/10/2-legged-vs-3-legged-oauth/

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to doorkeeper to make client applications auto-approved, so that the user won't be involved:

```
skip_authorization do |resource_owner, client|
  # return true to skip authorization
  client.superapp? || resource_owner.admin?
end
```

Taken from [doorkeeper wiki](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/wiki/Skipping-application-authorization).